# Determining whether a tuple is a subset of a list of other tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to determine whether a given tuple is a subset of a list of other tuples.

I have a list of tuples, for examples:

```
list_of_fails = list([[(1,2,3)],
                      [(1,2,5)],
                      [(1,4,3)]])
```

I would like to determine whether a given tuple is a subset of any of these tuples, for instance the tuple

```
(1,2)
```

The result here would be yes,yes,no

I am able to do this when my tuples are list, for instance the following code will produce what i want:

```
list_of_fails = list([[1,2,3],
                      [1,2,5],
                      [1,4,3]]) 

for sublist in list_of_fails:

    if (set([1, 2]).issubset(sublist) == True):
        print("yes")
    else: print("no")
```

However converting each of my embedded tuples to a list seems rather inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to check this?

Comment: Does the order matter? That is, would `(1, 3)` or `(5, 2)` be considered to be a "subset" of one of the tuples in the example? Also, is the size of the tuples in the list and/or the size of the given tuple to search always the same?

Comment: Order does not matter. The tuples are the output of a itertools.combination function. So (1,3) and (5,2) would be considered subsets here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to go a level deeper. Using set operations is quite efficient already.

```
%%timeit
for sublist in list_of_fails:
    for i in sublist:
        if set((1, 2)).issubset(i):
            print("yes")
        else: print("no")
#Output:
yes
yes
no
363 µs ± 91.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

With itertools.combinations:

```
%%timeit
l = list(combinations(range(1,6), 2))
for sublist in list_of_fails:
    for i in sublist:
        for j in l:
            if set(j).issubset(i):
                print(j, i, "yes")
            else: print(j,i, "no")
#Output:
(1, 2) (1, 2, 3) yes
(1, 3) (1, 2, 3) yes
(1, 4) (1, 2, 3) no
(1, 5) (1, 2, 3) no
(2, 3) (1, 2, 3) yes
(2, 4) (1, 2, 3) no
(2, 5) (1, 2, 3) no
(3, 4) (1, 2, 3) no
..... and so on

23.8 ms ± 1.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Compact and quick with list comprehensions:

```
%%timeit
[print(j, i,"yes") if set(j).issubset(i) else print(j, i, "no") for sublist in list_of_fails for i in sublist for j in l]
#Output:
(1, 2) (1, 2, 3) yes
(1, 3) (1, 2, 3) yes
(1, 4) (1, 2, 3) no
(1, 5) (1, 2, 3) no
(2, 3) (1, 2, 3) yes
(2, 4) (1, 2, 3) no
(2, 5) (1, 2, 3) no
...and so on
18.3 ms ± 1.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, the list comprehension solution is both compact and fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the tuple to a list is actually not that much of a performance problem. I quickly tested this using the following code:

```
import random
import time

t0 = time.time()

rs = []
for i in range(10000):
    r1, r2 = random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)
    t = (r1, r2)
    l = list(t)
    rs.append(l)

t1 = time.time()

print(t1 - t0)
```

In the second run I uncomment the `l = list(t)` line and change `rs.append(l)` to `rs.append(t)`. The results I get are:

```
0.04108595848083496
0.037944793701171875
```

That's like 3ms per 10.000 `list()` calls on 2-sized tuples.

I'd say your solutions is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_fails = list([[(1,2,3)],
                      [(1,2,5)],
                      [(1,4,3)]])

for sublist in list_of_fails:
    if set((1, 2)).issubset(sublist[0]):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```